# How can I send http messages from android app( physical device) to my local server using mobile hotspot

Tags: android

what i am doing.

1. I start xampp server.
2. I make connection mobile(Micromax 117) hotspot  with laptop
3. In my device there is app from that i want to send request to local server. I 
   am using local IP address(IPv4) which is display on cmd in url.

Like :- http://192.168.50.32:9090/

Here 9090 is my port number

code: -

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.43.18:9090/");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
           connection.setDoInput(false);
           connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String br = bufferedReader.readLine();
            do {
                Log.e("Data is", br);
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,br,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } while (br != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "doInBackground:" + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I just want to know connection is working or not But nothing Working.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in local host you need to use 10.0.2.2
or if your computer is connected to network, you need to make the server listen to your network ip address.

try this method once

```
public String  performPostCall(String requestURL,
    HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

URL url;
String response = "";
try {
    url = new URL(requestURL);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);


    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
        }
    }
    else {
        response="";    

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return response;
 }
```

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is used for virtual device. It's not for physical device, I have physical device (micromax 117 with 4.2.1 version) as i mention in query. any way thanks.